# Strange behaviour with radiobutton

Tags: android

Hello everybody and thanks in advance:

I have some radiobuttons in my app and I have noticed something strange. The thing is that when I slightly touch the radiobutton, the touching event it seems to trigger but the round coloured check point does not appear, however if I touch it with a normal pression the round coloured check now appears.

Can anybody tell me why this occurs? Is there any way to avoid this and get always the round coloured check visible whether you touch either slightly or normal pression on it?.

Thank you for your attention and answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

Coloured check point(CCP) draw with animation. 
So if you touch slightly of point you may have not see a animation, because she played only if user have a correct touch. This situation produced only if you touch already checked element.